# DCOS doesn't allocate resources

Tags: marathon, dcos

I'm running simple DCOS cluster for testing using one master and two private nodes. First day I installed Kafka and did some tests, everything was working correctly.
However after restarting the cluster, Kafka had failed state, after restarting it was heathly again but it had no brokers. After a while I discovered that it's because second node was completely unused.

When first node has 100% CPU usage, the rest of tasks just wait instead of running on the second node and they have Waiting status in Marathon. That second node always has 0% CPU and 0% RAM allocation without any changes. All tasks run only on first node.
That second node is in healthy state and it shows correctly, I can ssh from master to it without any problems. Restarting doesn't work.

How can I fix this? I don't know where to search.

@edit:

kafka json:

```
{
  "id": "/kafka",
  "cmd": "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MESOS_SANDBOX/libmesos-bundle/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=$(ls $MESOS_SANDBOX/libmesos-bundle/lib/libmesos-*.so) && export PATH=$(ls -d $MESOS_SANDBOX/jre*/bin):$PATH && ./scheduler/bin/kafka-scheduler server ./scheduler/conf/scheduler.yml",
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 3072,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "*"
  ],
  "env": {
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LEADER_IMBALANCE_CHECK_INTERVAL_SECONDS": "300",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSET_METADATA_MAX_BYTES": "4096",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_PRODUCER_PURGATORY_PURGE_INTERVAL_REQUESTS": "1000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS": "6000",
    "BROKER_STATSD_PORT": "0",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LEADER_IMBALANCE_PER_BROKER_PERCENTAGE": "10",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_CONTROLLED_SHUTDOWN_MAX_RETRIES": "3",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_DEDUPE_BUFFER_SIZE": "134217728",
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/opt/mesosphere/lib",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_CONTROLLER_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS": "30000",
    "BROKER_JMX_REMOTE_AUTH": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_LOAD_BUFFER_SIZE": "5242880",
    "BROKER_MEM": "2304",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_QUEUED_MAX_REQUESTS": "500",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_IO_BUFFER_LOAD_FACTOR": "0.9",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR": "3",
    "BROKER_COUNT": "1",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_QUOTA_CONSUMER_DEFAULT": "9223372036854775807",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL_VERSION": "0.10.0.0",
    "BROKER_HEALTH_CHECK_MAX_FAILURES": "3",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_DELETE_RETENTION_MS": "86400000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_TOPIC_SEGMENT_BYTES": "104857600",
    "BROKER_CPUS": "1",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_FLUSH_OFFSET_CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MS": "60000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_COMMIT_TIMEOUT_MS": "5000",
    "JAVA_HOME": "./jre1.8.0_121",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE": "true",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_THREADS": "1",
    "JAVA_URI": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/java/jre-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS": "1",
    "PHASE_STRATEGY": "INSTALL",
    "ENABLE_BROKER_HEALTH_CHECK": "true",
    "BROKER_JMX_REMOTE_SSL": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_QUOTA_PRODUCER_DEFAULT": "9223372036854775807",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_GROUP_MIN_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS": "6000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_SOCKET_RECEIVE_BUFFER_BYTES": "102400",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_COMPRESSION_TYPE": "producer",
    "BROKER_HEALTH_CHECK_DELAY_SEC": "15",
    "BROKER_JMX_REMOTE_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH": "false",
    "KAFKA_ADVERTISE_HOST_IP": "true",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS": "30000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS": "600000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES": "104857600",
    "BROKER_HEALTH_CHECK_GRACE_SEC": "10",
    "BROKER_PORT": "9100",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_TOPIC_COMPRESSION_CODEC": "0",
    "BROKER_JMX_ENABLE": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_ENABLE": "true",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR": "1",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_ROLL_JITTER_HOURS": "0",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_SEGMENT_DELETE_DELAY_MS": "60000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_SOCKET_SEND_BUFFER_BYTES": "102400",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_BACKGROUND_THREADS": "10",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_IO_BUFFER_SIZE": "524288",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_NUM_REPLICA_FETCHERS": "1",
    "BROKER_JMX_REMOTE_PORT": "9999",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_METRICS_NUM_SAMPLES": "2",
    "OVERRIDER_URI": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/kafka/assets/1.1.19-0.10.1.0/overrider.zip",
    "BROKER_JMX_REMOTE_ENABLE": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_AUTO_LEADER_REBALANCE_ENABLE": "true",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE": "true",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_NUM_RECOVERY_THREADS_PER_DATA_DIR": "1",
    "BROKER_HEAP_MB": "2048",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_TOPIC_NUM_PARTITIONS": "50",
    "USER": "root",
    "PLACEMENT_STRATEGY": "NODE",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_RETENTION_MINUTES": "1440",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_FLUSH_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL_MS": "9223372036854775807",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_IO_MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND": "1.7976931348623157E308",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_OFFSETS_COMMIT_REQUIRED_ACKS": "-1",
    "BROKER_JMX_REMOTE_REGISTRY_SSL": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_QUOTA_WINDOW_SIZE_SECONDS": "1",
    "FRAMEWORK_PRINCIPAL": "kafka-principal",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_HIGH_WATERMARK_CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MS": "5000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS": "168",
    "RECOVERY_GRACE_PERIOD_SEC": "1200",
    "BROKER_HEALTH_CHECK_INTERVAL_SEC": "10",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS": "600000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_INDEX_INTERVAL_BYTES": "4096",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_RESERVED_BROKER_MAX_ID": "1000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_BACKOFF_MS": "15000",
    "REPLACE_DELAY_SEC": "600",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES": "1000012",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_IP": "2147483647",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANER_MIN_CLEANABLE_RATIO": "0.5",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_ROLL_HOURS": "168",
    "DISK_TYPE": "ROOT",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_INDEX_SIZE_MAX_BYTES": "10485760",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_QUOTA_WINDOW_NUM": "11",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_FETCH_MIN_BYTES": "1",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS": "30000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MESSAGES": "9223372036854775807",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS": "300000",
    "EXECUTOR_URI": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/kafka/assets/1.1.19-0.10.1.0/executor.zip",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_TIME_MS": "2000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_LAG_TIME_MAX_MS": "10000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_NUM_NETWORK_THREADS": "3",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT_VERSION": "0.10.0",
    "FRAMEWORK_NAME": "kafka",
    "KAFKA_URI": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/kafka/assets/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_CONTROLLED_SHUTDOWN_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS": "5000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_NUM_PARTITIONS": "1",
    "BROKER_HEALTH_CHECK_TIMEOUT_SEC": "20",
    "ENABLE_REPLACEMENT": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_GROUP_MAX_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS": "300000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES": "1048576",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_CONTROLLED_SHUTDOWN_ENABLE": "true",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_METRICS_SAMPLE_WINDOW_MS": "30000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_NUM_IO_THREADS": "8",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_SEGMENT_BYTES": "1073741824",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_PREALLOCATE": "false",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES": "-1",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_FETCH_WAIT_MAX_MS": "500",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_FETCH_PURGATORY_PURGE_INTERVAL_REQUESTS": "1000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY": "delete",
    "BROKER_DISK": "5000",
    "KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_URI": "master.mesos:2181",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_FETCH_BACKOFF_MS": "1000",
    "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_REPLICA_SOCKET_RECEIVE_BUFFER_BYTES": "65536",
    "KAFKA_VER_NAME": "kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0"
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "timeoutSeconds": 5,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 0,
      "portIndex": 0,
      "path": "/admin/healthcheck",
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "ignoreHttp1xx": false
    }
  ],
  "labels": {
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_RELEASE": "39",
    "DCOS_SERVICE_SCHEME": "http",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_SOURCE": "https://universe.mesosphere.com/repo",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_COMMAND": "eyJwaXAiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9kb3dubG9hZHMubWVzb3NwaGVyZS5jb20va2Fma2EvYXNzZXRzLzEuMS4xOS0wLjEwLjEuMC9iaW5fd3JhcHBlci0wLjAuMS1weTIucHkzLW5vbmUtYW55LndobCJdfQ==",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_METADATA": "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",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_REGISTRY_VERSION": "3.0",
    "DCOS_SERVICE_NAME": "kafka",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_FRAMEWORK_NAME": "kafka",
    "DCOS_SERVICE_PORT_INDEX": "1",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_VERSION": "1.1.19.1-0.10.1.0",
    "DCOS_MIGRATION_API_PATH": "/v1/plan",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_NAME": "kafka",
    "MARATHON_SINGLE_INSTANCE_APP": "true",
    "DCOS_PACKAGE_IS_FRAMEWORK": "true",
    "DCOS_MIGRATION_API_VERSION": "v1"
  },
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10001,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "name": "health",
      "labels": {}
    },
    {
      "port": 10002,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "name": "api",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ],
  "uris": [
    "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/java/jre-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz",
    "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/kafka/assets/1.1.19-0.10.1.0/scheduler.zip",
    "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/kafka/assets/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz",
    "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/libmesos-bundle/libmesos-bundle-1.9-argus-1.1.x-3.tar.gz"
  ],
  "fetch": [
    {
      "uri": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/java/jre-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    },
    {
      "uri": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/kafka/assets/1.1.19-0.10.1.0/scheduler.zip",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    },
    {
      "uri": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/kafka/assets/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    },
    {
      "uri": "https://downloads.mesosphere.com/libmesos-bundle/libmesos-bundle-1.9-argus-1.1.x-3.tar.gz",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    }
  ],
  "readinessChecks": [
    {
      "name": "kafkaUpdateProgress",
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "path": "/v1/plan",
      "portName": "api",
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "timeoutSeconds": 10,
      "httpStatusCodesForReady": [
        200
      ],
      "preserveLastResponse": true
    }
  ],
  "upgradeStrategy": {
    "minimumHealthCapacity": 0,
    "maximumOverCapacity": 0
  }
}
```

example app that can't run on second node too:

```
{
  "id": "/sleepscript",
  "cmd": " while :; do echo 'Hit CTRL+C'; sleep 1; done",
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 128,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 0,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "*"
  ],
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10000,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

@edit2:

These are some interesting lines from logs, I'm trying to run few instances of the same task so first node is used at 100%( *.11 node) and second node is empty( *.12 node):

```
Sep 04 09:07:01 master-1 java[2406]: [2017-09-04 09:07:01,682] INFO  Finished processing e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1269 from 10.132.0.11. Matched 0 ops after 1 passes. ports(*) 1025->2180,2182->3887,3889->5049,5052->807
9,8082->8180,8182->9380,9383->29823,29825->32000; disk(*) 50100.0; disk(*) 6270.0; mem(*) 8639.0 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-81)
Sep 04 09:07:01 master-1 java[2406]: [2017-09-04 09:07:01,682] INFO  Finished processing e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1268 from 10.132.0.12. Matched 0 ops after 1 passes. ports(*) 1026->2180,2182->3887,3889->5049,5052->807
9,8082->8180,8182->9099,9101->32000; disk(*) 50100.0; disk(*) 1263.0; cpus(*) 0.5; mem(*) 9279.0 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-81)
Sep 04 09:07:01 master-1 mesos-master[1963]: I0904 09:07:01.683557  1994 master.cpp:4732] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1269 ] for framework a5370699-baae-4e77-a48e-1283d36b1906-0000 (m
arathon) at scheduler-88e19c66-42c6-48be-be03-662a9312cd91@10.132.0.10:15101
Sep 04 09:07:01 master-1 mesos-master[1963]: I0904 09:07:01.683799  1994 master.cpp:4732] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1268 ] for framework a5370699-baae-4e77-a48e-1283d36b1906-0000 (m
arathon) at scheduler-88e19c66-42c6-48be-be03-662a9312cd91@10.132.0.10:15101
```

In second mode, there's this line different from first node: cpus(*) 0.5;
I guess that first node shows now CPUs because all are used, however second one shows 0.5 CPU, does it mean half CPU?

These are first offers where 0.11 node accepts one offer and runs one instance:

```
Sep 04 09:06:56 master-1 mesos-master[1963]: I0904 09:06:56.671070  1998 master.cpp:7029] Sending 2 offers to framework a5370699-baae-4e77-a48e-1283d36b1906-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88e19c66-42c6-48be-be03-662a9312cd91@10.132.0
.10:15101
Sep 04 09:06:56 master-1 java[2406]: [2017-09-04 09:06:56,675] INFO  Offer [e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1266]. Considering resources with roles {*} without resident reservation labels. Not all basic resources satisfied: c
pus NOT SATISFIED (1.0 > 0.5), mem SATISFIED (128.0 <= 128.0) (mesosphere.mesos.ResourceMatcher$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-75)
Sep 04 09:06:56 master-1 java[2406]: [2017-09-04 09:06:56,675] INFO  Offer [e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1265]. Considering resources with roles {*} without resident reservation labels. Not all basic resources satisfied: c
pus NOT SATISFIED (1.0 > 0.0), mem SATISFIED (128.0 <= 128.0) (mesosphere.mesos.ResourceMatcher$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-75)
Sep 04 09:06:56 master-1 java[2406]: [2017-09-04 09:06:56,676] INFO  Finished processing e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1266 from 10.132.0.12. Matched 0 ops after 1 passes. ports(*) 1026->2180,2182->3887,3889->5049,5052->807
9,8082->8180,8182->9099,9101->32000; disk(*) 50100.0; disk(*) 1263.0; cpus(*) 0.5; mem(*) 9279.0 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-75)
Sep 04 09:06:56 master-1 java[2406]: [2017-09-04 09:06:56,676] INFO  Finished processing e74ab83d-b856-4c89-a5fb-0eccb4e74268-O1265 from 10.132.0.11. Matched 1 ops after 2 passes. ports(*) 1025->2180,2182->3887,3889->5049,5052->807
9,8082->8180,8182->9380,9383->29823,29825->32000; disk(*) 50100.0; disk(*) 6270.0; mem(*) 8639.0 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-75)
```

Still, it shows like *.11 node has 0 CPU, but the last log shows that it passed and later there are logs with ID of running task.

@edit3:

Bingo, after creating tasks using 0.1 CPU finally *.12 node is used using all that 0.5 CPU it has. That node also can't run more than two 0.2 CPU tasks at once, so it seems that this 0.5 CPU is limiting it. It seems that something restricts it to 0.5 CPU but I have no idea what.

@edit4:

DCOS shows all 2 CPUs for that node, mesos UI shows also 2 CPUs as total, /proc/cpuinfo also shows two cores.

@edit5:

I "fixed" the problem by deleting /var/lib/dcos/mesos-resources and entire content of /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta directory. However I don't know what caused this problem in first place.

@anotherEdit

mesos/master/slaves content when working incorectly:

```
{"slaves":[{"id":"6c620a26-7bc6-4287-b67a-de2b0eb8778c-S3","hostname":"10.132.0.12","port":5051,"attributes":{},"pid":"slave(1)@10.132.0.12:5051","registered_time":1504683660.37257,"reregistered_time":1504683660.37296,"resources":{"disk":52824.0,"mem":11839.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":2.0,"ports":"[1025-2180, 2182-3887, 3889-5049, 5052-8079, 8082-8180, 8182-32000]"},"used_resources":{"disk":50100.0,"mem":7168.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":1.3,"ports":"[7000-7001, 7199-7199, 9000-9001, 9042-9042, 9160-9160]"},"offered_resources":{"disk":0.0,"mem":0.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":0.0},"reserved_resources":{"cassandra-role":{"disk":50100.0,"mem":5376.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":1.5,"ports":"[7000-7001, 7199-7199, 9001-9001, 9042-9042, 9160-9160]"}},"unreserved_resources":{"disk":2724.0,"mem":6463.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":0.5,"ports":"[1025-2180, 2182-3887, 3889-5049, 5052-6999, 7002-7198, 7200-8079, 8082-8180, 8182-9000, 9002-9041, 9043-9159, 9161-32000]"},"active":true,"version":"1.2.2","reserved_resources_full":{"cassandra-role":[{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.5},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"5827371e-2139-4278-99b5-85e7dd573f4c"}]}}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":4096.0},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"c5c881b0-45df-458b-9731-11cfb1b251c3"}]}}},{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.5},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"1fed2809-f03e-4600-bfa7-b83a382dafbb"}]}}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":1024.0},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"3fa104ed-8fec-47ce-9702-6cde32bc97de"}]}}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":9001,"end":9001}]},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"072d9c13-4205-4ab0-bff2-59e2604774c1"}]}}},{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.5},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"c06733c6-fe7e-43a1-a3b7-70371d7cae08"}]}}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":256.0},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"18b050cf-f45d-4e2d-8e32-b7d7028d4939"}]}}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":7000,"end":7001},{"begin":7199,"end":7199},{"begin":9042,"end":9042},{"begin":9160,"end":9160}]},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"f49161b4-071f-45e6-9316-62b81c009f8a"}]}}},{"name":"disk","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":50100.0},"role":"cassandra-role","reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"359a466c-1191-441e-8058-d77c84fbdf0f"}]}},"disk":{"persistence":{"id":"0df2d25d-8c64-42ac-ab65-1de63392b5e8","principal":"cassandra-principal"},"volume":{"mode":"RW","container_path":"volume"},"source":{"type":"MOUNT","mount":{"root":"\/dcos\/volume0"}}}}]},"used_resources_full":[{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.5},"role":"cassandra-role","allocation_info":{"role":"cassandra-role"},"reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"1fed2809-f03e-4600-bfa7-b83a382dafbb"}]}}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":1024.0},"role":"cassandra-role","allocation_info":{"role":"cassandra-role"},"reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"3fa104ed-8fec-47ce-9702-6cde32bc97de"}]}}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":9001,"end":9001}]},"role":"cassandra-role","allocation_info":{"role":"cassandra-role"},"reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"072d9c13-4205-4ab0-bff2-59e2604774c1"}]}}},{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.5},"role":"cassandra-role","allocation_info":{"role":"cassandra-role"},"reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"c06733c6-fe7e-43a1-a3b7-70371d7cae08"}]}}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":4096.0},"role":"cassandra-role","allocation_info":{"role":"cassandra-role"},"reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"c5c881b0-45df-458b-9731-11cfb1b251c3"}]}}},{"name":"disk","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":50100.0},"role":"cassandra-role","allocation_info":{"role":"cassandra-role"},"reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"359a466c-1191-441e-8058-d77c84fbdf0f"}]}},"disk":{"persistence":{"id":"0df2d25d-8c64-42ac-ab65-1de63392b5e8","principal":"cassandra-principal"},"volume":{"mode":"RW","container_path":"volume"},"source":{"type":"MOUNT","mount":{"root":"\/dcos\/volume0"}}}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":7000,"end":7001},{"begin":7199,"end":7199},{"begin":9042,"end":9042},{"begin":9160,"end":9160}]},"role":"cassandra-role","allocation_info":{"role":"cassandra-role"},"reservation":{"principal":"cassandra-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"f49161b4-071f-45e6-9316-62b81c009f8a"}]}}},{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.3},"role":"*","allocation_info":{"role":"slave_public"}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":2048.0},"role":"*","allocation_info":{"role":"slave_public"}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":9000,"end":9000}]},"role":"*","allocation_info":{"role":"slave_public"}}],"offered_resources_full":[]},{"id":"6c620a26-7bc6-4287-b67a-de2b0eb8778c-S2","hostname":"10.132.0.11","port":5051,"attributes":{},"pid":"slave(1)@10.132.0.11:5051","registered_time":1504683660.32389,"reregistered_time":1504683660.32425,"resources":{"disk":56370.0,"mem":11839.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":2.0,"ports":"[1025-2180, 2182-3887, 3889-5049, 5052-8079, 8082-8180, 8182-32000]"},"used_resources":{"disk":512.0,"mem":2048.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":0.6,"ports":"[23803-23805]"},"offered_resources":{"disk":0.0,"mem":0.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":0.0},"reserved_resources":{"kafka-role":{"disk":5000.0,"mem":2560.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":1.0,"ports":"[1025-1025, 9100-9100]"}},"unreserved_resources":{"disk":51370.0,"mem":9279.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":1.0,"ports":"[1026-2180, 2182-3887, 3889-5049, 5052-8079, 8082-8180, 8182-9099, 9101-32000]"},"active":true,"version":"1.2.2","reserved_resources_full":{"kafka-role":[{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.5},"role":"kafka-role","reservation":{"principal":"kafka-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"b722808d-79a2-4871-8c97-e95a2c847fbd"}]}}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":256.0},"role":"kafka-role","reservation":{"principal":"kafka-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"6eb2865d-f823-473f-8c69-49a72eb7dbf6"}]}}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":1025,"end":1025}]},"role":"kafka-role","reservation":{"principal":"kafka-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"dynamic_port","value":"API_PORT"},{"key":"resource_id","value":"1deb5417-7852-49fb-ac81-fceb073369a8"}]}}},{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.5},"role":"kafka-role","reservation":{"principal":"kafka-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"fe21a9d8-0ba0-4d82-9bae-ca252d72bf93"}]}}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":2304.0},"role":"kafka-role","reservation":{"principal":"kafka-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"1beca7e2-bf10-43be-be28-0f93b03eac37"}]}}},{"name":"disk","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":5000.0},"role":"kafka-role","reservation":{"principal":"kafka-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"d7e9cb00-2204-481a-a999-cec4fee5d248"}]}},"disk":{"persistence":{"id":"661b8d81-8d33-432d-bd47-5538718730f9","principal":"kafka-principal"},"volume":{"mode":"RW","container_path":"kafka-volume-11c8a735-646f-4c46-9af5-ac2cbc52b697"}}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":9100,"end":9100}]},"role":"kafka-role","reservation":{"principal":"kafka-principal","labels":{"labels":[{"key":"resource_id","value":"99c8303c-1892-4fb8-bd0f-8618ad877654"}]}}}]},"used_resources_full":[{"name":"cpus","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":0.6},"role":"*","allocation_info":{"role":"slave_public"}},{"name":"mem","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":2048.0},"role":"*","allocation_info":{"role":"slave_public"}},{"name":"disk","type":"SCALAR","scalar":{"value":512.0},"role":"*","allocation_info":{"role":"slave_public"}},{"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":23803,"end":23805}]},"role":"*","allocation_info":{"role":"slave_public"}}],"offered_resources_full":[]}],"recovered_slaves":[]}
```

Comment: Can you post your application JSON? I suspect you have some constraints or reservation that prevents your application from running on second agent.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I edited my main post and posted json files in it

Comment: In marathon logs you should be able to see information about Mesos offers and why they were declined. JSONs looks good. There might be something wrong with agents configuration e.g. reserved resources.

Comment: Thanks, I found necessary info in logs. It seems that really there's something wrong with agent resources but I have no idea where can I search for removing these weird limits. I edited my post. I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Can you post the json returned by http://<master_node>/mesos/master/slaves?

Comment: I "fixed" the problem by deleting /var/lib/dcos/mesos-resources and then cleaning entire /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta. To this point everything works fine however I don't know what caused this problem. Anyway, I'm putting json in main post if you want it.

Comment: I had this problem again(updated that json file in main post) and I can confirm that deleting entire /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta on each node fixes this problem. It happened after shutting down and booting all machines in cluster so it seems that DC/OS can't handle cluster shutdowns.